# connecting to cellular networks using java on PC

Tags: java

Can I access to some cellular networks such as GSM, UMTS, LTE, WiMAX, etc. using java on PC. I need to get some of their parameters such as data rate and delay.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is not supported by the Java standard libraries.

If it is possible to access these networks *at all* on your PC<sup>1</sup>, it would be best to do it using utilities provided by the OS or 3rd party (non-Java) applications.  I don't have any recommendations.

There may be other options with Java ME or Android; e.g.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/meep/api/javax/microedition/cellular/CellularNetwork.html

However, it is not "immediately obvious" if these will give you the data you are looking for.

---

<sup>1 - Obviously, it would require the appropriate hardware and OS-supported software.</sup>